# Is DataApi Reliable and Practically Real Time? Extremely Delayed

Tags: android, wear-os, google-api-client, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-notification

I have had an Android Wear app on the market for about 10 months now and it's stopped working (Not sure when it stopped working).

I'm trying to update my wearable application with some statistics that I record in my mobile app. As I say, this used to work fine and reliably. I even added the timestamp to this so it was unique as the `onDataChanged` is only called if data has changed. This guarantees that.

**My Issue**

I can submit the `PutDataMapRequest` fine by calling `Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem` and I get a successful callback in my `ResultCallback`.

The `onDataChanged` usually gets called in the end but the delay is just too much and more than it used to be. Whatsmore, I know it's being set correctly because I have an app that I launch, in which I have an `Activity` that I go and get the `DataItems` and there is a backlog there. I am having the same issue with `onDataChanged` in this `Activity` also.

**What I Have Done**

1. Made sure the versionCode and versionName matches across both module `build.gradle` files.
2. Ensured both `build.gradle` files use the same versions of the support and google services libraries.
3. Ensured both classes are connecting to `GoogleApiClient`
4. Made sure the data is different each time to force it to call `onDataChanged` in the service. I don't need this but just to get it working.

**My Code**

*Mobile*

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            PutDataMapRequest putDataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create(path);
            putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString("content", content);
            putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString("title", title);
            putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putLong("timestamp", DateTime.now().getMillis());
            PutDataRequest request = putDataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();    

            Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
                            if (!dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                Log.e("WearDevice", "buildWatchOnlyNotification(): Failed to set the data, "
                                        + "status: " + dataItemResult.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                            } else {
                                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Notificaiton result callback returned successfully: "+dataItemResult.getDataItem().toString());//: "+node.getDisplayName());
                            }
                        }
                    });
}
```

*Wear*

I have a service which extends `WearableListenerService`. This is declared in the manifest like so.

```
<service android:name=".NotificationUpdateService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Here is my service.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
        if (MainActivity.DEBUGGING)
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDataChanged");
        for (DataEvent dataEvent : dataEvents) {

            if (dataEvent.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
                DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataEvent.getDataItem()).getDataMap();
                String content = dataMap.getString("content");
                String title = dataMap.getString("title");
                if ("/mydatapath".equals(dataEvent.getDataItem().getUri().getPath())) {
                    buildWearableOnlyNotification(title, content, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The `buildWearableOnlyNotification` method creates and starts a foreground notification and this works fine when it's actually called.

Comment: Is your app using Google Play services 8.3?

Comment: Yes all of the latest libraries are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now need to set the [urgent flag](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/PutDataMapRequest.html#setUrgent()) if you want your data to be synced immediately, otherwise the framework will batch up those calls and do them in one call which means you can see up to 30 minutes delay; it is a change made in the most recent Play Services to preserve the battery when such immediate data sync is not really needed.

Comment: I assume this has changed at some point because it used to work fine?

Comment: This is the new default behavior in the latest version of the Play Services.